# Can a Python setuptools entry script have the same name as the package it is in?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, python-packaging

I'm trying to fix some broken python packages, distributed through bioconda or conda-forge. Many of them have a script that has been used as an entry point with the same name as the package itself, for example bigscape.py in the bigscape package, a genomics tool.

When I try to use setuptools to create entry scripts for these, I want them to have the same name as the original script did, such as `somepackage.py`. I'm using setuptools `console_script` to create these entry scripts:

```
     entry_points={
         'console_scripts': ['somepackage.py=somepackage.somepackage:main']
     },
```

However, when the package has been installed with `pip install`, the original script `somepackage.py` will be in the `site-packages` directory as expected, but when I try to run the installed `somepackage.py`, I see the message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'somepackage.somepackage'; 'somepackage' is not a package
```

I have a complete minimal reproduction like this:

```
.
├── setup.py
└── src
    └── somepackage
        ├── __init__.py
        └── somepackage.py
```

setup.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from distutils.core import setup

setup(
     name='somepackage',
     packages=['somepackage'],
     package_dir={'somepackage': 'src/somepackage'},
     entry_points={
         'console_scripts': ['somepackage.py=somepackage.somepackage:main']
     },
     description='test'
     )
```

somepackage.py

```
def main():
    print("I am running inside the package")
```

I am able to resolve this by changing what the entry script is called, like so:

```
     entry_points={
         'console_scripts': ['some_other_name.py=somepackage.somepackage:main']
     }
```

However, existing users are used to calling the package by `/the/path/to/somepackage.py` and a changing executable name could be confusing.

Is there some way that I'm missing to specify that when the entry script runs, it should import the package in site-packages rather than importing itself? The problem seems to be that when the entry script is called `somepackage.py` it cannot find the package `somepackage`, and instead ends up importing itself. It would also be possible to change the name of the package, but that would create naming confusion for existing users as well.

Finally, in the case of bigscape, `bigscape.py` cannot be copied as an executable script using setuptools' `scripts` functionality because `bigscape.py` references other files relative to itself, meaning it must be run within the package directory and not from the python environment's `bin` directory.

Comment: can you test it as `'console_scripts': ['somepackage=somepackage.somepackage:main']`